# Database geocode tune rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, geocoding

So I'm trying to write my own geocode database for US and Canada, because I need incredible speed, and no rate limiting. I've got the following algorithm for rails batch geocoding, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to eager load the initial batch of cities. I've been benchmarking, and I've gotten it down to this algorithm which gives me 1000 geocodes in about 19 seconds, with ~50% coverage.

My question is, would there be a better way to operate instead of re-querying the database when trying to "drill down"?

```
ids = City.where('lower(name) IN (?)', locations).pluck(:id) # Eager load the only possible results
results.find_each do |r|
  #next if r.location = 'EXACT'
  names = r.location.split(',')
  state = get_state(names)
  city = City.where(:id => ids, :state => state[0]).where('lower(name) IN (?)', names).first # Drill down to the appropriate state

  if city.nil?
    city = City.where(:id => ids).where('lower(name) IN (?)', names).first # Hail Mary
  end

  # Return if nil?
  if city.blank?
    puts "Oh no! We couldn't find a city for #{r.location}"
  else
    # Finally, the city
    puts "Selected #{city.name} for #{r.location}"
    r.latitude = city.latitude
    r.longitude = city.longitude
    r.save
  end
end
```

Comment: You are doing something I am trying to do. How did you setup Geocoder to call on your database and not an API? As I do not want to use Google or any other service to call on. I am trying to setup so that a User can find another registered member nearby. So I need to call on the zipcodes database that has the latitude/longitudes with zips codes.

Comment: Email me with your specific needs. Zip codes are a lot easier than city/place names. I've been planing on open sourcing this project/idea, because it's not that hard. bwheeler96 [at] gmail.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I could think of is checking out [find_in_batches](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html) and increase your batch size.  `find_each` defaults to 1000 - I'm guessing you could probably tune that a bit for performance.

Comment: Updated my answer since state is just a string...  Let me keep pondering this for a bit...

Comment: Maybe instead of going from the City level to the State level, go the other way - from State to City.  So, iterate over the state and then do cities in that state only?  Just kind of speculating at this point.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely the best improvement I was able to make, because of the sheer volume of the cities the cities, was to hit the database once only.

Rune the `.where` query, and then use

```
array.select { |x| ... }[0]
```

to filter results. This cut my benchmark down by 3/4. (20 seconds to 4.8 seconds)